# Exporting LyX to LaTeX append filepath in \includegraphics

Tags: lyx

When I export LyX file to LaTeX, I get 
`\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{1D__User-Folder_Fig1.pdf}`. Then I do have to make manual changes in LaTeX document. I wonder how to force LyX to give  `\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{Fig1.pdf}` rather than `\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{1D__User-Folder_Fig1.pdf}`.

**UPDATE**

I'm using LyX 2.1.0beta1 and Windows 7.

Comment: I don't quite follow: `1D__User-Folder_Fig1.pdf` and `Fig1.pdf` are distinct file names. Do you mean some folder structure instead?

Comment: The file name is `Fig1.pdf` but after exporting I'm getting `1D__User-Folder_Fig1.pdf` where `1` is figure number and  `D:\User\Folder` is the file path.

Comment: If the images are in the same folder that the lyX document, only the file name is exported (at least in Linux).

Comment: As it stands, this sounds like a Lyx bug. However, to be sure I think we need to know a bit more. Could you edit in a demo `.lyx` file and give details of how your graphics are laid out. It probably would be useful to include Lyx version and operating system too.

Comment: @JosephWright: Please my update.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've just run a few tests with exactly that version and have no problems. However, I really think we need to see the part of your `.lyx` file that relates to the graphic. Open the `.lyx` file in Notepad, search for the bit with the graphic and edit it in here. My guess is you have something odd going on there. (I guess two lines, `\begin_inset Graphics` followed by `filename <demo-graphic>.pdf`.)

Comment: @MYaseen208 Still could do to see your `.lyx` file: I doubt an answer is possible without it.